# iBooks ePubs lost all cover art after iOS5 update

Tags: ipad, ios, books

After I upgraded to iOS 5 on my iPad 2, iBooks no longer shows any cover art for ePubs that I have imported. Anything that is from the iBook store shows art fine, along with PDFs.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I found that if you remove the books from the iPhone, then add them again via sync the cover art should return.

Comment: I have a lot of books on my iPad. Is deleting and re-adding them the only way to get back the cover art? I would really hate to have to go this route.

Comment: Telling iTunes not to sync books, syncing, then enabling book sync, syncing, starting iBooks and *waiting* will cause the books to get art. This will take a while and seems to involve some sort of indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all iBooks form the iPad and the re-sync them again that fixes it.